# How to send SFMC SMS via external API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, sms

I'm trying to trigger SFMC REST API to send SMS from Postman. Below is the steps:

1. Created a Outbound SMS content in Mobile Connect (with the following properties)

   - Template type: Outbound - API Triggered
   - Next Keyword: OPTIN
   - Message: Hello world message
   - Message Status: Active/Scheduled
   - API Key: xxxx
2. Trigger SFMC REST API using Postman client

   - Call https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken (with client ID and Secret) to obtain the access token
   - Call https://subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/xxxx/send with the following json

   {
   "mobileNumbers": [
       "85296xx57xx" //My HK number
   ],
   "SendTime": "2018-12-11 04:08"
   }

   - It responses a token ID: yyyyy
   - Call https://subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/xxxx/deliveries/yyyyy to check the status delivery. It returns unknown token message

After performing the above steps, I still not able to receive the SMS. Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is the number opted-in to the keyword? Are you able to send to that Contact normally in MobileConnect?

Comment: @WenHao, Did you find any solution to this problem. I am having the same.

Comment: @RSuri make sure your recipient is opt-in for the SMS. Go to the Contact Builder > All Contact to check for it.

Comment: @WenHao, thanks for your response. contact has been added manually and source column is showing manual. what else is needed to resolve this. Are keywords required for this?

Comment: @RSuri - yes, the keyword is the opt in.